# Choice of the names of the notes for harmonica tuned in keys different from C

Tags: scales, harmonica

I was looking around the [website](http://us.playhohner.com/instruments/harmonicas/diatonic-harmonicas/marine-band-series/marine-band-crossover/) of one of the most important maker of harmonica and I checked the tuning chart of an harmonica in the A key.

I am beginning to study harmonica and expected to find on the holes from 4 to 7 the scale of A. When playing a harmonica in C I get the scale of C major, so I was half expecting to find A major or (maybe) some bluesy variation on it.

This is the tuning of an A harmonica, starting from hole 4, till hole 7:

A4 - B(H)4 - Db5 - D5 - E5 - F#5 - Ab5 - A5

With equal temperament, these pitches, would correspond, of course, to those that I was expecting (Three sharps: F#, C#, G#).

They mention that this harmonica features a "modern compromise tuning": note that I find it to be the same for the [classic model](http://us.playhohner.com/instruments/harmonicas/diatonic-harmonicas/marine-band-series/marine-band-1896-classic/) of the harmonica so the compromise must be somewhere else (maybe the temperament is not equal?). They market the Crossover type of harmonica as more versatile, and I have no doubt that this is true: does this versatility depend on this choice of the notes?

And most of all: why the peculiar choice of names for the notes? Why calling it Db5 instead of C#5? Why Ab5 instead of H#5 (btw, in the scale of A one would naively expect that A is not lowered or raised)? I suppose that this kind of tuning must be in some sense natural but I need some help to figure out why is it so.

Answer (score 2):

Since in A key we all know that there are three sharps and zero flats, I believe they also know what they're doing and call the notes appropriately, so F# is really F# and Ab is really Ab. I cannot believe they are messing with names. That is, probably, the best compromise they can achieve with this particular kind of harmonica. So its Ab will be a bit lower than a G# played on an electric keyboard or any other instrument with precise pitch.

Answer (score 1):

Being a German firm, I believe, their B/H is understandable. However, they do seem confused with notes from key sigs.  I can't believe it's due to other tunings apart from 12edo. Although because each harp is actually dedicated to a particular key, somewhat like early harpsichords, etc., it could be that they are accurately tuned, and they call the notes appropriately. But I doubt it. It must have lost something in the translation...

Be interesting to see Hohner's take on notes on a chromatic!

Comment: The B/H4 is fine, but I am confused by the mix of flat and sharp notes. Since they are the oldest maker of harmonicas I presume that they know what they are doing...

Comment: You have an interesting point on the chromatica. Here it is: http://us.playhohner.com/instruments/harmonicas/chromatic/chromonica-line/super-chromonica/ and again it is a mix of # and b ...

Comment: It's interesting, but they're not alone. I work with some guitarists who talk their language!!

Comment: With the chromatic, I'd almost expect them to name all altered notes sharpened, because that's what the button in does. Thus C>C#, G>G#, even, maybe, E>E#, but I think they are just confused. A chat with them might clear it up. Speak German?

Answer (score 0):

The Crossover is not standard tuning.  So the Crossover harmonica is tuned differently than their other standard harmonicas.  Start with a standard model with standard tuning if you're just beginning harmonicas.  Then move on to the specialized harps.  Have fun.